# Dataset error "Table doesn't have a primary key." when using XmlRead()

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I get the error "Table doesn't have a primary key." so how do I set the primary keys, does it not do this when I call ReadXml() or have a missed a arg out??

`MemoryStream msXml = new MemoryStream(byteArray); 

 DataSet dsXml = new DataSet();

 dsXml.ReadXml(msXml);

 string s = "123456789";

 DataRow foundRow = dsXml.Tables["Accounts"].Rows.Find(s);`

**EDITED**

Here is a basic [example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml) of the format of my xml file. How would I set primary keys for each CD?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, just a quick suggestion.. Try set the MissingSchemaAction property to "AddWithKey" on your DataSet and see if that works?

Comment: Does the xml file have to have ID's in it or will the dataset do this for me?

Comment: I believe the XML file needs to have the ID's (unique), which will be the PK for that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for you help I managed to fingure it out. Example below worked for me if it helps anyone else.

`DataSet dsXml = new DataSet();

dsXml.ReadXml(msXml);

DataTable tbl;

tbl = dsXml.Tables["Accounts"];

tbl.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { tbl.Columns["Id"] };`

Answer (score 0):

You are reading XML data into your dataset, but not the Schema, which is where a PK would be defined.

The error is thrown when you use the Find method which requires a Pk, which is not defined.

Either define one manually after loading the data or save/load both xml and schema.